# Convert string type date type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a two input fields with bootstrap datepicker.

```js
$('#from').datepicker({
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true
});
$('#to').datepicker({
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true
});

$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var date1 = $("#from").val();
    var date2 = $("#to").val();
    if (date2 < date1) {
      console.log(new Date(d1));
      $("#dateerror").html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><a 
        href = "#"
        class = "close"
        data - dismiss = "alert"
        aria - label = "close" > & times; < /a> <
        strong > Opps! < /strong> Invalid Dates</div > ');

        $("input[type=text]").val("");
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="start date" class="form-control" id="from" name="from" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="end date" class="form-control" id="to" name="to" required>
```

The variable date1 and date2 is getting from input fields.When i compare date1 with date2 i can't getting correct ouput.How to convert date1 and date2 to date format to compare both?

Comment: Please format code carefully. **edit** Now there are too much indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `getDate()` method of the datepicker:

```
var date1 = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
var date2 = $("#to").datepicker("getDate");
```

Comment: This should actually be the accepted answer! Didn’t think of datepicker’s method! 

Answer (score 2):

```
var myDate = new Date("February 19, 2018")
```

or in your case:

```
var date1 = new Date($("#from").val())
var date2= new Date($("#to").val())
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

```js
var yy = Date.parse("February 19, 2018");

var xx = Date.parse("March 21, 2012");

var timeDiff = Math.abs(xx - yy);
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays)
var message="xx is small";
if (yy< xx) {
 message="yy is small";
 }
console.log(message)
```

I would suggest you better to go with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)  for more inbuilt function.

Comment: Hahah first you delete your initial answer due to downvotes to post the same again, then you propose momentjs for a simple string to date conversion!? LOL

Comment: @ArberSylejmani Because you forget to remove down vote after i update my answer.

Comment: Yup! may i'll give up vote wrongly you.  I think Barmar answer would be get the upvote.

Comment: Barmar’s answer is actually the correct one, I’m not saying mine is wrong, but you need to keep things simple, and his is the simplest way to do it, while yours is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It's not a complicated. I just explained additional activities.

Comment: You can write a whole thesis here but that’s not what the question was. He didn’t want to see the days difference, just a simple string to date conversation. Anyway, I’m over and out!

Comment: Do I look like I care for your or anyone’s vote? The idea of Stackoverflow is to help and be helped, what you do with your votes is none of my business aka I don’t care if you use your downvotes as an argument 

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply